# what is the depth first search node expansion sequence of this graph

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

I am trying to figure out the sequence of nodes expansion of this graph when using applying DFS.

[image]
Should the sequence be A, B, C, D, E, G or A, B, D, E, G

Assuming ties are resolved in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do DFS, choosing nodes in alphabetical order, the first path you find to G will be `A, B, C, D, E, G`.